# How can I prevent my cat from developing pressure sores on his legs?

Tags: cats, health

Hunter (our 11 year old neutered male with a heart condition diagnosed this summer) has developed a small wound on one of his hind legs. This summer he started spending more time laying on the hard tile floor. He has also lost a lot of weight since being diagnosed with the heart condition.

I believe that the wound is a pressure sore from his (now bony) legs resting on the hard tile floor for hours at a time. I cleaned and bandaged it. If it begins to worsen or does not improve I will immediately take him to the vet, but stress from the vet worsens his heart condition, and our normal vet is unfamiliar with this heart condition (restrictive cardiomyopathy - our normal vet has only ever seen one other case before). I am currently waiting for a callback from his cardiologist.

Is there another surface that I can provide for him that will be cooling (the reason I think he's laying on the tile) but isn't as hard on his body? Or, would it be reasonable to keep both hind legs bandaged to provide some extra padding on the bones? ([this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003NS3A8U) is the type of bandage we're using)

Comment: Blanket over icepack?

Comment: what if you adapt one of those gel pillows as a bed for your cat?